# Integrating $ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{\cosh(t)+x}} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: integration

Can this be solved with a simple change of variables?

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{\cosh t+x}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

The "$\cosh t$" is not a typo. This is the inner integral of a double integral. I will integrate the result with respect to $t$.

Comment: Do you actually mean $\cosh(t)$, or should that be $\cosh(x)$?

Comment: The integral is written correctly yeah. Cosh(t).

Comment: This is an inner integral in a double integral, after this I will integrate wrt t.

Comment: Do we really need to restrict our methodology to simple change of variables? Notice that the answer is $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{\cosh t+x}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{|t|}{\sqrt{\cosh t-1}} $$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How did you end up with that? Can you give a hint please?

Answer (score 3):

Write $a = \cosh t$. By substituting $u = \sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+x}}$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)\sqrt{a+x}}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a-1}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^2} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a-1}} \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{a+1}}\right).
\end{align*}

By using trigonometric identities

- $2\operatorname{arctanh}(x) = \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right) $ for $-1 < x < 1$;
- $\operatorname{arccosh}(x) = \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\right)$ for $x \geq 1$;

we can further simplify to

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)\sqrt{a+x}}
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-1}} \operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}}{a} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-1}} \operatorname{arccosh}(a).
\end{align*}

Finally, using the fact that $\operatorname{arccosh}(\cosh t) = |t|$, we obtain

> $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{\cosh t+x}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{|t|}{\sqrt{\cosh t-1}} $$

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped me finish my argument. Kudos!